# Installing nw.js in debian returns error "version `GLIBC_2.14' not found"

Tags: linux, glibc, node-webkit, eglibc

I'm trying to install `node-webkit` in debian `64 bit` . 
I tried the steps in [github](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/The-solution-of-lacking-libudev.so.1) 
and its returning error,

```
version GLIBC_2.14 not found
```

I'm not able to install `glibc`. How can I get rid of this ?

Comment: You probably need to build it from sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Just run the `script`

```
echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get -y update
apt-get -t testing install libc6-dev
```

followed by the script in `github` and then `node-webkit` works fine